# How to split with comma skipping comma between '?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have that string :

```
a = "Hello, my name is Peter, John"
```

I tried to split such as :

```
a.split(",")
```

But I got that :

```
["Hello", "my name is Peter", "John"]
```

But I would like to get that :

```
["Hello", "my name is Peter, John"]
```

Comment: What do you mean, skipping comma between'?  there is no `'` in your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second argument of the split function to define how many times you want the string to be spitted (counting from the beginning). Setting it to `1` should solve your problem:

```
a.split(",", 1)
```